# How would I change the code to allow for words from a text file to populate the tree instead of hardcoding words?

Tags: c, tree, trie

I'm creating a Trie that reads from a "Dictonary.txt" and adds it to the tree. I would like to ask how to code a function that reads a text file and adds it to the tree. I haven't really found any tutorials that I could understand how to achieve this.

I hope you can help me. I would also be happy with some useful links that step by step teach me how it could possibly be done.

```
// C implementation of search and insert operations
// on Trie
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define ARRAY_SIZE(a) sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])

// Alphabet size (# of symbols)
#define ALPHABET_SIZE (26)

// Converts key current character into index
// use only 'a' through 'z' and lower case
#define CHAR_TO_INDEX(c) ((int)c - (int)'a')

// trie node
struct TrieNode
{
    struct TrieNode *children[ALPHABET_SIZE];

    // isLeaf is true if the node represents
    // end of a word
    bool isLeaf;
};

// Returns new trie node (initialized to NULLs)
struct TrieNode *getNode(void)
{
    struct TrieNode *pNode = NULL;

    pNode = (struct TrieNode *)malloc(sizeof(struct TrieNode));

    if (pNode)
    {
        int i;

        pNode->isLeaf = false;

        for (i = 0; i < ALPHABET_SIZE; i++)
        pNode->children[i] = NULL;
    }

    return pNode;
}

// If not present, inserts key into trie
// If the key is prefix of trie node, just marks leaf node
void insert(struct TrieNode *root, const char *key)
{
    int level;
    int length = strlen(key);
    int index;

    struct TrieNode *pCrawl = root;

    for (level = 0; level < length; level++)
    {
        index = CHAR_TO_INDEX(key[level]);
        if (!pCrawl->children[index])
            pCrawl->children[index] = getNode();

        pCrawl = pCrawl->children[index];
    }

    // mark last node as leaf
    pCrawl->isLeaf = true;
}

// Returns true if key presents in trie, else false
bool search(struct TrieNode *root, const char *key)
{
    int level;
    int length = strlen(key);
    int index;
    struct TrieNode *pCrawl = root;

    for (level = 0; level < length; level++)
    {
        index = CHAR_TO_INDEX(key[level]);

        if (!pCrawl->children[index])
            return false;

        pCrawl = pCrawl->children[index];
    }

    return (pCrawl != NULL && pCrawl->isLeaf);
}

// Driver
int main()
{
    // Input keys (use only 'a' through 'z' and lower case)
    char keys[][8] = {"the", "a", "there", "answer", "any",
                 "by", "bye", "their"};

    char output[][32] = {"Not present in trie", "Present in trie"};


    struct TrieNode *root = getNode();

    // Construct trie
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE(keys); i++)
        insert(root, keys[i]);

    // Search for different keys
    printf("%s --- %s\n", "the", output[search(root, "the")] );
    printf("%s --- %s\n", "these", output[search(root, "these")] );
    printf("%s --- %s\n", "their", output[search(root, "their")] );
    printf("%s --- %s\n", "thaw", output[search(root, "thaw")] );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: Your code looks more like c rather than c++. Redarding reading from files in c++ you should refer to the [c++ standard I/O library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ okay I will change the tags.